is it impossible to work on ros1_bridge ros-noetic version on ubuntu 22.04 ros2 humble?
I have a laptop that has ubuntu22.04 ros2-humble installed and I want to install ros1_bridge ros-noetic but I want make sure it is possible before trying. because I see alot of documents saying that I should use ubuntu20.04 for humble and noetic oh and I tried docker for ros-melodic and I want to go for trying ros1_bridge ros-noetic
